# alias with custom text and wildcard label in graphite

Tags: graphite

lets imagine i'm having this query in graphite:

`level1.level2.*.level4.count`

and I want my alias to be
`level is: level3` but simply I can't find the way.

After reading [graphite docs](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html) for few hours, I still can't find simple way to do it.

Even more challenging would be to do regex function ex:

`aliasByRegex(
query, 
'level is: level$1',
'/level2.level[0-9].level4/')`

Is it possible to do something like this in graphite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use [aliasByNode](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.aliasByNode) to extract the exact level and then [aliasSub](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.aliasSub)

```
aliasSub(aliasByNode(level1.level2.*.level4, 2), "(.*)", "level is \1")
```

Of course you could use aliasSub alone, but imo it would make the regex the way complicated.

Comment: yes, that is more or less what I was looking for...
thanks!